# How to disable loop for ParticleEmitterComponent on visionOS?

Tags: swift, visionos, vision-pro, reality-composer-pro

In Reality Composer Pro there is a flag to toggle the loop of the particle system. In code I couldn't find a `.loop` value on the `ParticleEmitterComponent` - does anyone know how else I can disable the looping there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To disable the loop you have to set the `.timing` value to **once** like this:

```swift
var particles = ParticleEmitterComponent()
particles.timing = .once(warmUp: 0, emit: .init(duration: 1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Besides the `.once(...)` case of the `timing` enum, you can use the fantastic `burst()` instance method which emits `burstCount` particles on the next update call. Here's the code:

```
import SwiftUI
import RealityKit

struct ContentView : View {
    @State var particles = ParticleEmitterComponent()
    let entity = Entity()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Burst") {
                particles.isEmitting = false     // important

                entity.components.remove(ParticleEmitterComponent.self)
                entity.components[ParticleEmitterComponent.self] = pSystem()
            }
            RealityView { content in
                content.add(entity)
            }
        }
    }       
    func pSystem() -> ParticleEmitterComponent {
        particles.emitterShape = .sphere
        particles.burstCount = 1500
        particles.burst()
        return particles
    }
}
```

[image]